# A Riley from the Future

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, acrostic

This is my last one for the day; I’ve been heavily focused on my story riddle and am coming up on the revision process so I’ve crafted another simple Riley for the community to give a glimpse of what is to come.

> Sneak in the prefix, while hunting for boar; beware of bobcats, their swift silent roar.
>
> Ask for the infix, obviously straight; oh, no that’s a lie, oh well, too late.
>
> Indeed yes the suffix, similar to here; maybe that was the lie, in that is my fear.
>
> Lift your spirits, keep your head high; you’ll find the answer, as always with time.

Comment: The acoustic says SAIL.

Comment: Acoustic lol gotta love auto correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is

> Boat

Sneak in the prefix, while hunting for boar; beware of bobcats, their swift silent roar.

> Boar with silent "oar" from "roar" leaves **B**. Also, there is **B** alliteration used with "beware the bobcat"

Ask for the infix, obviously straight; oh, no that’s a lie, oh well, too late.

> The letter is not straight, and again, the repetition of "oh" and the letter **o** indicates the infix is the round letter **O**

Indeed yes the suffix, similar to here; maybe that was the lie, in that is my fear.

> The key here is the word "that" and the phrase "in that". Within "that is" **AT**, the suffix

And the acrostic

> spells sail which leaves you with **sail boat**

I'm not sure about the future and time aspect of it, though.

Comment: The reason for the title is explained prior to the riddle. This is a sneak peak at what my next story riddle is centered on. Very good work on solving this one!